# Filter admin post list with multiple filters; how to structure query object with logical AND operator

Tags: wordpress

I need assistance understanding how to structure the WP_query object to apply multiple criteria / filters.

In this case, I'm currently filtering the admin post list using two get variable, that should BOTH match the resulting posts list. I can get this to work fine for one variable but not both.

After the get variable is set, the following works perfectly to filter the admin post lists by a single get variable (labelled "Notification" in the get variable, and an ACF database key of "author_notified").

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'filter_admin',15 );

function filter_admin( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'post' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['Notification']) && $_GET['Notification'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'author_notified';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['Notification'];
    }

}
```

This results in a query object where WP_query[query_vars][meta_key] and WP_query[query_vars][meta_value] target the desired subset of posts.

How should the query object be structured to target a subset of posts that matches two similar criteria simultaneously? Or more simply, how do I filter the admin posts lists by two criteria that must both be true?

I'm still pretty new to PHP/wordpress and unsure how to structure query objects. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you say it "does not seem to work" can you be more specific? e.g. Does it give an error, unexpected results, a black screen, or just has no effect? Also, what debugging have you done to see whats happening, e.g. is `posts_filter2` getting called? Is the if clause getting triggered? Can you show us what it looks like when you print out your `$get_query` array? It's easier to debug something like this if you can see the output that and we can work back from there.

Comment: Thanks FluffyKitten. The function posts_filter2 is called; but no filtering takes place - the posts are all visible. Thanks for the pointer re: printing out the $get_query array, I'm trying that now...

Comment: In the first method, the filter works by setting WP_query[query_vars][meta_key] to author_notified , and WP_query[query_vars][meta_value] to the correct value (0 or 1). How should WP_query be structured to achieve two filtering criteria? This is the big gap in my knowledge - it looks like [query_vars] will only handle single values, and does not accept logical arrays as values.  Do I need to use WP_query[meta_query] instead of WP_query[query_vars]?

Comment: Glad you got sorted! I always find that it helps to see exactly what's in the array you're passing to wp_query. FYI, I see you changed your question - I actually think the code in your original question could be helpful to other users because they could well be trying to achieve this in the same way.

Comment: Ah, good point. It's mostly in the answer but I'll add it back to be sure it's searchable. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved, many thanks to troubleshooting tips from @FluffyKitten.

The WP_query object should be structured as follows to achieve multiple filters to the admin posts list. Essentially, ACF fields can be added with logical operators to WP_query[query_vars][meta_query]:

```
        [meta_query] => Array
            (
                [relation] => AND
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => author_notified
                        [value] => 1
                        [compare] => =
                        [type] => NUMERIC
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => recommended_decision
                        [value] => 0
                        [compare] => =
                        [type] => CHAR
                    )

            )
```

This query object structure can be accomplished with a function as follows, assuming GET variables named "Notification" and "Recommendation" have already been set elsewhere:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'posts_filter2',15 );

function posts_filter2( $query ){
   global $pagenow;
   $type = 'post';
   if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
       $type = $_GET['post_type'];
   }
   if ( 'post' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php') {

        $queryParamsCounter = 0;
        if (isset( $_GET['Notification'] ) && $_GET['Notification'] != '')
        {
          $notification = (int)$_GET['Notification'];
          $queryParamsCounter++;
        }
        if (isset( $_GET['Recommendation'] ) && $_GET['Recommendation'] != '')
        {
          $queryParamsCounter++;
          $recommendation = $_GET['Recommendation'];
        }

        $meta_query = array();

        if ($queryParamsCounter > 1) {
          $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
        }

        if (isset($notification)) {
          $meta_query[] =       array(
            'key' => 'author_notified',
            'value'    => $notification,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',  
          );
        }
        if (isset($recommendation)) {
          $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'recommended_decision',
            'value'   => $recommendation,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'CHAR',
          );
        }

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);

    }
}
```

Note that if only one filter is selected the relation key should not be used.

I hope this helps others facing the same challenge!